# Reconstruct dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I have two dictionaries created from a config file:

```
    dict1 = {'x':'A', 'y':'B', 'z':'C'} # decoding ABCs
    dict2 = {'ID1': ('x','n1'), 'ID2': ('y','n2'), 'ID3':('z', 'n3') }
```

I want to create a new dictionary in the following format:

```
    final = {'A':{'ID1':'n1', 'ID2':'n2'}, 'C':{'ID3':'n3'}, ...}
```

I did not come up with a clever way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Should that second `'A'` be a `'B'`?

Comment: You can't. You cannot create a dictionary with duplicate keys. I see how `'x'` maps to `'A'` via `dict1`, but you need to work out how to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: @jamylak: I rolled back your edit. You can't just assume something is a typo and change the meaning of the question like that.

Comment: @interjay would make a lot of sense though

Comment: Gosh you guys are fast:) Actually it was intended, but of course it does not make sense.  A, B, and Cs can occur multiple times.

Comment: Apart from the great answers and your fast responses, there is still an issue I am struggling with understanding here, perhaps it is nothing. But why do you have the inner dicts keys in the form 'ID#' as a string, and they are spread out to all the outer keys. It seems that if I want the value for ID2 I need to look in all the outer keys before I find the inner key to ID2, also, it means an outer key, lets say 'F' would have seemingly arbitrary inner keys like ID32, ID35 ... etc.. there seems to be no order to this, perhaps you should rethink this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
final = {}
for id, (x, n) in dict2.items():
    final.setdefault(dict1[x], {})[id] = n
```

which creates

```
{'A': {'ID2': 'n2', 'ID1': 'n1'}, 'C': {'ID3': 'n3'}}
```

Don't know if this meets your needs, but at least it's a valid structure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming x, y, z in dict2 and A, B, C in final:

```
final = {dict1[k]: {id: v} for id, (k, v) in dict2.items()}
```

---

```
In [6]: dict1 = {'x':'A', 'y':'B', 'z':'C'}

In [7]: dict2 = {'ID1': ('x','n1'), 'ID2': ('y','n2'), 'ID3':('z', 'n3') }

In [8]: {dict1[k]: {id: v} for id, (k, v) in dict2.items()}
Out[8]: {'A': {'ID1': 'n1'}, 'B': {'ID2': 'n2'}, 'C': {'ID3': 'n3'}}
```

---

If you really did mean there should be two As, then it cannot be expressed as a dict. Will a list of pairs do? You'll have to decide on an ordering then.

```
In [10]: [(dict1[k], {id: v}) for id, (k, v) in dict2.items()]
Out[10]: [('A', {'ID2': 'n2'}), ('C', {'ID3': 'n3'}), ('A', {'ID1': 'n1'})]
```

Comment: which leads to *one* `'A'` key replacing the other. It'll be arbitrary which one wins.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That may be a copy/paste mistake in the original question.

Comment: I assumed the second A and the second x are typos — it just doesn't make any sense otherwise.

Comment: Oh wait, he *could* have meant that there should be two `A`s.

Comment: It seems quite a stretch to assume that there were two independent typos which have the same meaning. More likely, OP doesn't know dicts can't have multiple keys.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Hopefully corrected in a meaningful way now. I am aware that one cannot have multiple identical keys.